# Removing header and footer in Word inserts Paragraph character

Tags: office-interop

I'm trying to remove all footers in my simple .doc document using interop. The code

```
foreach (Section sect in oDoc.Sections)                
{
 foreach (HeaderFooter headFoot in sect.Footers)
 { headFoot.Range.Delete(); }
}
```

inserst in every footer new paragraph character.Sometimes it transfers text into next page to new page. my investigation tells me that paragraph is inserting on accessing headFoot.Range object... So headFoot.Range.Text = String.Empty takes no effect too.
I also tried

```
 try { oDoc.StoryRanges.Item(WdStoryType.wdEvenPagesFooterStory).Delete(); }
                catch { }

                try { oDoc.StoryRanges.Item(WdStoryType.wdFirstPageFooterStory).Delete(); }
                catch { }

                try { oDoc.StoryRanges.Item(WdStoryType.wdPrimaryFooterStory).Delete(); }
                catch { }
```

, but this code does not remove footers. So is there any ideas how can avoid Paragraph character insertion while removing footers?